# Number increments too much

Tags: c#, list, datagrid

I've got a `DataGrid`, which is bound to a `List`: `_bhaList`.

[image]

Now, I've written a method which will allow the user to select an item on the grid, and move it up. And as it moves up, the `No.` column is updated to show it's current position. However, in this particular case, where I have 3 items, if I choose `No. 2`, and move it up, it does switch places with `No. 1`, and those numbers update, but `No. 3` will change to 4. If I repeat the process, the new `No. 4` will change to 5.

[image]

Here's the code that I've attempted:

```
var oldIndex = grdBha.SelectedIndex;
var newIndex = oldIndex - 1;
var bha = _bhaList[oldIndex];

_bhaList.RemoveAt(oldIndex);

bha.Number = oldIndex;

_bhaList.Insert(newIndex, bha);

for (var i = newIndex + 1; i <= _bhaList.Count; i++)
{
    if (i != _bhaList.Count)
    {
        _bhaList[i].Number += 1;
    }
}
```

I've tried different variations in the `for` loop, with no success.

I have the feeling that this is going to be something really simple, but my mind just isn't seeing it.

Comment: What happens if you drop the `for` loop entirely?

Comment: Does the item ever move more than one spot at a time? If not, why a loop? Only two items will ever be affected: the item moving, and the one immediately previous (with which it is swapping places).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that only two items in this case had their "order changed", yet you incremented the number for everybody *below* the item moved. In this case `Bit X/O Sub` was 3, but gets incremented to 4.

You know the only two indices involved:

```
// swap the two
var temp = _bhaList[newIndex];
_bhaList[newIndex] = _bhaList[oldIndex];
_bhaList[oldIndex] = temp;

_bhaList[newIndex].Number = newIndex + 1;
_bhaList[oldIndex].Number = oldIndex + 1;
```

Comment: Note that this will work fine as long as only two items are swapping positions. If the OP later allows users to drag/drop an item to somewhere else in the list, then a for mechanism would need to be implemented to update the No. column for affected rows.

Comment: @MadHenchbot: yep. When the OP asks that question, we can help solve it.

Comment: This was a serious case of "overthinking the problem". I had it in my head that I had to change everything. *falls back to earth* Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your items can only move one spot at a time the loop is unnecessary and can be replaced with the following:

```
_bhaList[oldIndex].Number++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to reshuffle/ swap the locations,

When you `_bhaList.Insert(newIndex, bha);` it will increment the count by 1.

Try only by `replacing` those two selected indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop doesn't make sence, you don't need to increase the number of each items. You only need to do this if you add a new item in the list.

```
var oldIndex = grdBha.SelectedIndex;
var newIndex = oldIndex - 1;
var oldBha = _bhaList[oldIndex];
var newBha = _bhaList[newIndex];

oldBha.Number--;
newBha.Number++;

_bhaList.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
_bhaList.Insert(newIndex, oldBha);
```

or

```
_bhaList[oldIndex] = newBha;
_bhaList[newIndex] = oldBha;
```

Answer (score 0):

by using

```
_bhaList.RemoveAt(oldIndex);

bha.Number = oldIndex;

_bhaList.Insert(newIndex, bha);
```

you have moved the item to the new index. .NET will push down all the other elements as required with out the need for you to do so.  As such there is no need for the `for` loop.

To resolve your issue, simply remove the for loop.